# GRE 9367 #62: Prove $X=[0,1]$ in lower limit topology ($[a,b)$) is not compact, is Hausdorff and is disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, separation-axioms

GRE9367 #62

> [image]

[Ian Coley](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%203%20solutions.pdf)'s solution:

> [image]

[Sean Sovine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qQg_AuKUglY0I1bkZ5azl6NDQ/view)'s solution:

> [image]

---

1. Prove $X$ is not compact.

My first proof was similar to Ian Coley's, but I came up with another proof:

> If $X$ is compact, then because $X$ is Hausdorff, $X$ is compact Hausdorff in both standard and lower limit topologies of $\mathbb R$. This implies that the topologies are equal by (*), a contradiction.

Did I go wrong somewhere?

2. Prove $X$ is Hausdorff.

My proof is similar to Sean Sovine's. For Ian Coley's proof, is my understanding right?

> If there exists the required open sets in standard topology, then we can choose the same sets as the required open sets in the lower limit topology.

3. Prove $X$ is disconnected.

> My proof is the same as Ian Coley's. Is Ian Coley's proof right?

---

(*) Munkres Exer26.1 ([dbfin pf](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/problem-1-solution/))

> [image]

Comment: @5xum [Munkres Exer26.1](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/problem-1-solution/) or [Compact Hausdorff Topology is Minimal Hausdorff](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_Topology_is_Minimal_Hausdorff) or something. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *How* did you get a contradiction? You can define two distinct Hausdorff compact topologies on the same set. But you can't if, furthermore, one of them is finer than the other one.
2. Yes, it is fine.
3. It is fine too.

Comment: [Munkres Exer26.1](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/problem-1-solution/)? I updated my question. Thanks José Carlos Santos!

Comment: Yes, that part was missing, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok now I get it. Didn't read properly I guess. Guess time to call it a day as well. Thanks again! ^-^

Answer (score 2):

$[0,1]$ is not connected, e.g. because $[0,\frac12)$ is a non-trivial closed-and-open subset of it.

Not compact as $\{1-\frac1n: n=2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$ is an infinite subset without limit point in it.

Hausdorff because as you state its topology includes the usual, Hausdorff, one.

Comment: $1-\frac1n$ was precisely my answer! I was afraid I was wrong somehow and that $1-\frac1{2^n}$ is for some reason a right choice. Thanks ^-^